# When making an and statement, I get an Syntax Error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

When making a tax calculator, I seem to continue to be getting an error at the "=" in the following line of code:

```
elif int(vermogen) >= 30001 and <= 100800:
```

But I can't see a way to fix this. I've tried removing the integers but that didn't help, I've also tried to change my symbols to > and < instead of <= >= but that also didn't help. I think I made an obvious mistake but I don't seem to find it. When removing the "=" behind the "<" The syntax error moves from the "=" to the "<".  I hope to hear from you soon. Here is the code I've been using/ It's in dutch, but that shouldn't affect anything.

```
vermogen = input('Hoeveelheid vermogen: ')
N_schijf1 = 30000
N_schijf2 = 70800
N_schijf3 = 877200

P_schijf2 = 424.8
P_schijf3 = 11403.6

if int(vermogen) <= 30000:
    print("Je betaalt 0 euro aan vermogensbelasting")

elif int(vermogen) >= 30001 and <= 100800:
    vermogen_betalen = int(vermogen) - N_schijf1
    betalen_vermogen = vermogen_betalen * 0.006
    print("Je betaalt",betalen_vermogen,"euro aan vermogensbelasting")

elif int(vermogen) >= 100801 and <= 978000:
    vermogen_betalen = int(vermogen) - N_schijf1 - P_schijf2
    betalen_vermogen = vermogen_betalen * 0.013
    tebetalen_vermogen = P_schijf2 + betalen_vermogen
    print("Je betaalt",tebetalen_vermogen,"euro aan vermogensbelasting")

elif int(vermogen) >= 978001:
    vermogen_betalen = int(vermogen) - N_schijf1 - P_schijf2 - P_schijf3
    betalen_vermogen = vermogen_betalen * 0.0161
    tebetalen_vermogen = P_schijf2 + P_schijf3 + betalen_vermogen
    print("Je betaalt",tebetalen_vermogen,"euro aan vermogensbelasting")

print("Test")
```

Comment: `and` is used to join complete conditions. Operands don't carry across the `and`. You can use `30001 <= int(vermogen) <= 100800`

Comment: `elif int(vermogen) >= 30001 and <= 100800` should be `elif int(vermogen) >= 30001 and int(vermogen) <= 100800`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a complete condition on each side of the `and`. Operands don't carry across the `and` into the next condition.

You could write:

```
int(vermogen) >= 30001 and int(vermogen) <= 100800
```

Or just:

```
30001 <= int(vermogen) <= 100800
```

since Python supports [chaining of comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your if from:

```
elif int(vermogen) >= 100801 and <= 978000:
elif int(vermogen) >= 30001 and <= 100800:
```

to

```
elif int(vermogen) >= 100801 and int(vermogen) <= 978000:
elif int(vermogen) >= 30001 and int(vermogen) <= 100800:
```